# Where did the FAQ go?

Tags: feature-request

It seems that in the site re-design, our FAQ got buried deep down in the page hierarchy https://askubuntu.com/helpcenter/on-topic.

How are new users supposed to find this?

Even when you ask new questions this is difficult to find.

Personally, this seems like a poor design decision as this is a very informative page describing the EOL versions of Ubuntu as well as dealing with bug reports as well as which OSes we support.

Can we bubble this up to make it more visible?

Comment: Just for the record, this has nothing to do with the redesign. It's [an update to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [post on MSO about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) indicates, [/helpcenter](https://askubuntu.com/helpcenter) is *not* meant to be read all at once. The individual parts of it are meant to be used as the resource when we refer to it in comments and the such.

[/about](https://askubuntu.com/about) on the other hand contains *all the information* important to a *new user* - That's why it's referred to as "the tour" now - an introduction to the site, how it works and what to look for.

The old "What's on-topic" part, for example, is also on /about, in the "**Get answers to practical, detailed questions**" section.

Comment: Wow. That's painful. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: @maggotbrain Yeah, a lot of changes are painful 'round here. I personally think "help center" was bad naming.

Comment: @Seth Yikes. I'd almost rather read a EULA. :-/ Personally, I think this just makes things more hostile for a new user. C'est la vie.

Comment: @maggotbrain I agree. "help" is very subjective. Especially *on* a support/help site..

Comment: Does this mean that new users wont be able to earn the Analytical badge any more? Since there isn't a faq or does the description need to change to "Read all pages of the help centre" and if they do is there adequate tracking in place to see that somebody has.

Comment: @WarrenHill I'd use the MSO QA for such questions - There [is no answer to that yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183439/210342).

Comment: @maggotbrain rofl "I'd rather read a EULA"